# control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type] (just a simple judge)

Tags: c++, return-type

```
struct node{
    TreeNode *SubNode;
    int depth;
};
int minDepth(TreeNode* root){
    queue<node> q;
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;
    node cur = {root, 1};
    q.push(cur);
    while(!q.empty()){
        node temp = q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(temp.SubNode->left == NULL && temp.SubNode->right == NULL)
            return temp.depth;
        if(temp.SubNode->left){
            node temp_ = {temp.SubNode->left, temp.depth+1};
            q.push(temp_);
        }
        if(temp.SubNode->right){
            node temp_ = {temp.SubNode->right, temp.depth+1};
            q.push(temp_);
        }
    }
}
```

The code are about Leetcode's minimum-depth-of-binary-tree.
By the way.What the error means?
Non-return?
But I have the return.Why show this error?

Comment: Have you tried putting the error/warning message into your favorite search engine?

Comment: You (and the compiler) do not trust your algorithm due to `while(!q.empty()`. Make it `while(true)`.

Comment: @orbitcowboy Do you have anything recommended about textMate plugins?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I had.But there no suitable ans...in baidu.com.

Comment: @DieterLücking What it means is it depend on the compiler? If I exchange a compiler.Would it be different?

Comment: @DieterLücking I have tried.But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: minDepth() should return int, but it won't for example if while() cycle ends.

Comment: I had try add a retrun in the end. But it show error too.

Comment: i am not aware of this syntax "node temp_ = {temp.SubNode->left, temp.depth+1};" maybe syntax like this "node  temp_ = temp.SubNode->left; temp.depth+=1;" ?

Comment: temp_ is a struct.So "struct struct_name = {submember1, submember2...,submembern}; " can be worked.By the way,I have tried this way.And it didn't worked.